# How to enable logging in the MongoDB Java-Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, database-connection, slf4j

I have been using MongoDB 4.2 recently in combination with java-driver 3.12.7.
After I created a new MongoDB project with the Version (MongoDB) 4.4 i also had to use the newest java-driver (for example java-driver 4.1 or 4.2).
(Btw I don't use maven or grandle).
Since I got the java-driver sync 4.2 I tried to connect to my database with my java app. The app worked fine with the combination MongoDB 4.2 & java-driver 3.12.7.

Unfortunately, I constantly receive the notification:

> com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.Loggers shouldUseSLF4J
> WARNING: SLF4J not found on the classpath.  Logging is disabled for the
> 'org.mongodb.driver' component

I looked up on MongoDB and found this:

> By default, logging is enabled via the popular SLF4J API. Logging is
> optional: the driver will use SLF4J if the driver detects the presence
> of SLF4J API (class org.slf4j.Logger) in the classpath. Otherwise, the
> driver will log a single warning via JUL (java.util.logging) and
> otherwise logging will be disabled.

Are there any solutions to solve the problem with SLF4J without using SLF4J?
I want to see the logs like before with JUL.
At the moment I'm using IntelliJ as my IDE and OpenJDK15.0.02.

After i updated MongoDB & the java-driver nothing worked for some reason.
I took this code as an example to show the problem. I put two System.out.println() in it where i get the Point1 & Point2 as expected. But however i cant get a connection to the database ?:

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;
import java.util.Arrays;

       

public class TestClass {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("hello1");
         MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("my URI stands here");
         MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("DatabaseMongo");
         MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("test");
         System.out.println("hello2");
         Document doc = new Document("name", "MongoDB")
                .append("type", "database")
                .append("count", 1)
                .append("versions", Arrays.asList("v3.2", "v3.0", "v2.6"))
                .append("info", new Document("x", 203).append("y", 102));
         collection.insertOne(doc);
    }
```

}

After the compiling i get this:

1. Point1
2. 15, 2021 1:14:43 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.Loggers shouldUseSLF4J
3. WARNING: SLF4J not found on the classpath.  Logging is disabled for the 'org.mongodb.driver' component
4. Point2
5. Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@5a4041cc. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=testcluster-shard-00-00.3lmlx.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=testcluster-shard-00-02.3lmlx.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=testcluster-shard-00-01.3lmlx.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]
6. here are some other reports which are maybe not important..
7. at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:453)
8. at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:447)
9. at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:27) //it is the line with insertOne
10. Process finished with exit code 1

The solution to the second problem: MongoDB Atlas-> connection -> add new database user and delete the "old" one. After this it works.

Comment: All uppercase is shouting.

Comment: WHat is the java version you use?

Comment: I'm using Java 15 @varman

Comment: Try after changing the java version to 8 using your ide.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't change the situation. i used this guide: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver/getting-started/quick-start/#new-mongoclient-api-since-3-7. I tried to connect like in quick start but it doesn't work at all. I get an error and after looking in the database it's nothing insert there.

Comment: The same topic you had linked has a "Prerequisites":  _MongoDB Driver. See [Installation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver/getting-started/installation/) for instructions on how to install the MongoDB driver_. If you install the driver as per the instructions, the logging will be on (and by default logging is on). You can also add SLF4J to your Maven (or Gradle) configuration.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help so far.  
I don't want to use Maven or Grandle (because i'm not using one of them) to install the driver as per the instructions. I got the jar file's from here: 
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-sync/4.2.2/
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/4.2.2/
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/bson/4.2.2/
I downloaded the jars from there and added them to my library. 
Everything except for JUL works fine @prasad_
I couldn't find any explanation on MongoDB (Installation) how to solve my problem with JUL.

Comment: As of MongoDB java Driver 4.0 [The driver no longer logs via JUL (java.util.logging). The only supported logging framework is SLF4J](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/upgrading/).

Comment: Thank you @prasad_ I got SLF4J and it works. I just thought that there might be a way to bypass the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior with 4.x Java driver releases.  The change is documented [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/upgrading/):

> The driver no longer logs via JUL (java.util.logging). The only supported logging framework is SLF4J.

You can use slf4j-jdk14.jar to route SLF4J API calls to JUL.